# What happens behind the scenes with Type Methods that return objects?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to abstract some functionality so let's say I don't want the user to create an instance of a class to get another instance of another class, I found that class methods exists in swift (aka Type Methods) so I was exploring them, how safe/right is doing the following:

```
public class Person {

    class func Greet() -> Greet {
        return Greet()
    }

}


public class Greet {

    public func sayHi(_ callback: () -> ()){
        callback()
    }
}

Person.Greet().sayHi{
    print("Hi you!")
}
```

I'd like to know how does this work behind the scenes. For example, let's say that at `Greet` class I'll be doing some networking, how will it work in terms of memory. Should I use static methods instead?

Comment: Not clear what you want. Threading and class structure are different things.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lower-camelCase for variable and function names and upper-camelCase for type names. Having a type and function have the same name is quite misleading, especially if you don't conform to the naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and your code don't make a lot of sense.

The `Greet()` class function in your `Person` class is basically a factory method that creates and returns a Greet object.

There's no real point in doing it that way. It's perfectly safe, but pointless. Instead just use:

```
let aGreet = Greet()
```

(Create a new `Greet` object directly.)

As for threads, your code does nothing with threads. Every part of the code you've posted runs on the main thread. Your class structure has nothing to do with threads.

As the other commenter points out, you need to learn and follow Swift naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower-case letters. Class and type names should start with Upper-case letters.